# Angularjs masonry image stacking

Tags: angularjs, jquery-masonry

I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/txBgTwsMU9C6z1F4oVbD?p=preview) that works how I want it to except, when I load the page first time (or refresh the page) all of the isotope elements are stacked on top of each other.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

```
<ul class="grid" masonry="true">
    <li ng-repeat="bike in bikes | filter: { model: nameFilter } | orderBy: order">
        <img ng-src="{{bike.picture}}" ng-click="open(bike)"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry. By stacking, I mean, all of the images appear on top of each other - instead of floating beside each other in a grid format. When I then sort the elements or resize the page it recalculates and fixes itself.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create your own directive to do this auto position for your image ?

Comment: No, I am happy with it how it is, the only thing is: how do I get the images to position correctly when the page loads first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to a call to `element.masonry("reload");` once all the images have finished rendering.

To do that you will need another directive, in order to know when an image has been added and when that image has been loaded, like this:

```
.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$emit('imageIn');
            element.bind('load', function() {
              scope.$emit('imageLoaded');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you will have to use that directive in your view, like this:

```
          <img ng-src="{{bike.picture}}" imageonload ng-click="open(bike)"/>
```

And in your `masonry` directive you will have to do something like this:

```
            var nImages=0;
            var nImagesLoaded=0;
            scope.$on('imageIn', function(){
              nImages++;
            });
            scope.$on('imageLoaded', function(){
              if(++nImagesLoaded===nImages)
                element.masonry("reload");
            });
```

## [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VUvvu4zM6sIF8bEq9ofl?p=preview)